# mysql backup/restore strategy for large datasets (more than 15GB)

Tags: mysql

I am handling few databases that is growing very fast. Now it is around 12GB and in next few months it will cross 15GB. At this situation I only have the traditional backup process **mysqldump** running in cronjob. I found significant delay in backup and restore time (hours, even days) for the whole database. Knowing that physical backups are much faster than logical, I found these two, but cannot implement those because of some limitations and company policy.

[MySQL Enterprise Backup](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup.html) : which is commercial

[Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) : Percona came with this tool specially for Linux environments. And not all companies will agree to use 3rd party tools even though it is open source.

Please suggest any other better backup and restore mechanism for big database specially when the databases are mix of  `Innodb` and `MyISAM`. Looking for some good suggestions on **snapshots**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally used Percona XtraBackup toolset. It does some simple procedures to get all the committed data in innodb binlog when it finishes the normal storage. Reading about MySQL Enterprise Backup also can do this.

Incremental backups/snapshots can be made with both Percona XtraBackup and MySQL Enterprise, if that's what you're looking for.

Using a read-only slave, you can maintain separation of the read locks. This will keep your locks from being held on the master read if you backup using mysql free tools.

Another option if you have a slave is you can shut off the slave and rsync the data somewhere for backup.

Comment: I don't know how consistent the data would be if you copy the data files directly.

Answer (score 1):

First I would try using "--single-transaction" with mysqldump as long as all your tables are innodb and you aren't modifying table structure during dump. This will attempt to dump from a single point in time but only when it can be performed without locking your tables.

I haven't tried xtrabackup but it looks like that will do what you want as well.

You could also try setting up mysql replication and dumping from the slave.

Lastly LVM snapshots but that takes a bit more work.